# django admin site - divide in sections object attributes

Tags: python, django

I've been playing around with the django admin site and so far I've been able to add some attributes into the view where all objects of a model are shown, however (as i have a lot of attributes in the model) i would like to know if there is a way to divide by sections the attributes of the object when creating or modifying the object so readability can be better.

I've been trying to find a way but I haven't found it. As english is not my native language maybe I'm not searching for the right key words.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would by grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried customizing/overriding the admin templates? Take a look [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates). That might be what you need. Good luck!